# Update char array with Int and float values, without sprintf?

Tags: c

I am using C to program a microcontroller (NHS3152) to calculate resistance using this formula:

**RES = (V1-V2)/I**

I want to write a program that:

1. Updates the values of 3 Floats and 1 integer (V1, V2, I, RES)
2. Update uint8_t text[] = "Char to store values of V_1, V_2, I, Res"; with a string with the values of these 3 floats and 1 integer
3. Commits text to memory using the function: "Example1_Creating_an_NDEF..." (provided below)

The issue I am having is with Updating text with the values of the 3 floats and 1 integer. I am able to do it with sprintf, however I cannot use this function with my microcontroller (I dont know why it stops me from flashing it to memory)

The code bellow is an example of what i want to achieve in from point 2 above, in the real code the float and integer values are updated by getting values from sensors on the mircocontroller:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <stdint.h>
static volatile float V_1 = 5.0; // store value of Voltage 1
static volatile float V_2 = 2.0; // store value of voltage 2 
static volatile int I = 5;  // store current value
static volatile float RES;  // calcualte resitance 
int i=1; 
uint8_t text[] = "Char to store values of V_1, V_2, I, Res";


int main(void)
{
    printf( text);
    printf("\n");
    //updates values for ADC_1, ADC_2, I, Res, 
    while(i<=2){ // real while loop is infinite 
        V_1 ++ ;  // Usually value updates from microcontroller sensor
        V_2 ++ ;  
        I ++;       
        RES = (V_1-V_2)/I; // calculating resistance 
        
        sprintf((char *)text, "Updated Text V1: %6.2f V2: %6.2f I: %8.d resistance: %e", V_1, V_2,I, RES ); // what i want to do but without sprintf
        printf( text); 
        printf("\n");  
        i++;
    }
    

    printf("END");
}
```

OUT:

```c
Char to store values of V_1, V_2, I, Res
Updated Text V1:   6.00 V2:   3.00 I:        6 resistance: 5.000000e-01
Updated Text V1:   7.00 V2:   4.00 I:        7 resistance: 4.285714e-01
END
```

Here is the Code including the function Example1_Creating_an_NDEF.. from point 3. This working code manages to Commit the text to memory (**it works**). All i need is to be able to **update the text without sprintf** as i believe these functions aren't allowed when i'm not in debug mode.

```c
#include "board.h"

// From ndeft2t
#include "ndeft2t/ndeft2t.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

uint8_t instance[NDEFT2T_INSTANCE_SIZE] __attribute__((aligned (4)));
uint8_t buffer[NFC_SHARED_MEM_BYTE_SIZE ] __attribute__((aligned (4)));
uint8_t locale[] = "en";
uint8_t text[] = "Char to store values of V_1, V_2, I, Res";


// I want to add these to the text message 
static volatile float V_1 = 5.0;
static volatile float V_2 = 2.0;
static volatile int I = 5;
static volatile float Res = ;



static void Example1_Creating_an_NDEF_Message_with_a_single_record_of_type_TEXT (void)
{

    Chip_NFC_Init(NSS_NFC); /* Is normally already called during board initialization. */
    NDEFT2T_Init();
    NDEFT2T_CreateMessage(instance, buffer, NFC_SHARED_MEM_BYTE_SIZE, true);
    NDEFT2T_CREATE_RECORD_INFO_T recordInfo = {.shortRecord = true, .pString = locale};
    if (NDEFT2T_CreateTextRecord(instance, &recordInfo)) {
        /* The payload length to pass excludes the NUL terminator. */
        if (NDEFT2T_WriteRecordPayload(instance, text, sizeof(text) - 1)) {
            NDEFT2T_CommitRecord(instance);
        }
    }
    NDEFT2T_CommitMessage(instance);
    /* The return value of the commit function is ignored here. */
}




int main(void)
{
    Board_Init();
    //NDEFT2T_Init();

    /* Optional feature: send the ARM clock to PIO0_1 */
    Chip_IOCON_SetPinConfig(NSS_IOCON, IOCON_PIO0_1, IOCON_FUNC_1);
    Chip_Clock_Clkout_SetClockSource(CLOCK_CLKOUTSOURCE_SYSTEM);

    /* Blink & attach a message to Memory */
    while (1) {
        //updates values for V_1, V_2, I, Res, 
        
        V_1++; 
        V_2++; 
        I++; 
        RES = (V_1 - V_2)/RES; 
        
        // Update the text message to contain "(V_1, V_2, I, RES)"
        LED_Toggle(LED_RED);
        Example1_Creating_an_NDEF_Message_with_a_single_record_of_type_TEXT();
        Chip_Clock_System_BusyWait_ms(500);
     }

    return 0;
}
```

---

### EDIT: responding to  KamilCuk's comment : Do you really need float? Does your mcu has floating point support? Consider using integers only.

The fucntions i use to get V1,V2 & I, all return an Integer (eg: V1=2931 12 bit converter so between 0 and 4096 ) however to convert the integer value to the real value i need to use the following conversion:

```c
V1_real= (V1* 1.2) / 2825 + 0.09; // CONVERSION added line
```

Without conversion i Cannot calculate Res.

An acceptable compromise is to commit to memory the values V1, V2, I without converstion to real values. I can then calculate RES in a second momemnt, once i retrieve the data from the MCU ( i am using my phone as an NFC reader, the chip is an NFC tag)

So the question is:

**How do i convert the message in text to a message containing the integers (V_1,V_2,I)? :**

Something like:

```c
uint8_t text[] = "Char to store values of V_1, V_2, I";
text = "Message with V_1: V_1value, V_2: V_2value, I: IValue
```

Below is the code i use to extract the value of V_1 & V_2:

```c
void adc (void) 
{

Chip_IOCON_SetPinConfig(NSS_IOCON, IOCON_ANA0_1, IOCON_FUNC_1);
Chip_ADCDAC_SetMuxADC(NSS_ADCDAC0, ADCDAC_IO_ANA0_1);
Chip_ADCDAC_SetInputRangeADC(NSS_ADCDAC0, ADCDAC_INPUTRANGE_WIDE);
Chip_ADCDAC_SetModeADC(NSS_ADCDAC0, ADCDAC_SINGLE_SHOT);
Chip_ADCDAC_StartADC(NSS_ADCDAC0);

//Getting the data
while (!(Chip_ADCDAC_ReadStatus(NSS_ADCDAC0) & ADCDAC_STATUS_ADC_DONE)) {
; /* Wait until measurement completes. For single-shot mode only! */
}

//Data V1 stored here
adcInput_1 = Chip_ADCDAC_GetValueADC(NSS_ADCDAC0);

// Usually i use this line to then conver it to the real value of V1
//adcInput_1= (adcInput_1 * 1.2) / 2825 + 0.09; // CONVERSION added line

//! [adcdac_nss_example_3]
}
```

Maybe someone has a better solution that allows me to actually arrive at having also RES calculated, knowing that:

```c
RES= V1_real-V1_real/I_real
V1_real= (V1* 1.2) / 2825 + 0.09 and 0< V1 < 4000 (12 bit converter for V1)
V2_real= (V2* 1.2) / 2825 + 0.09 and 0< V2 < 4000 
I_real = I*1e-12  0<I<4000
```

Comment: It's not hard to format integers with your own code, but formatting floats is complicated.

Comment: `I dont know why it stops me from flashing it to memory` Get to know why and solve the issue. Do you _really_ need `float`? Does your mcu has floating point support? Consider using integers only.

Comment: As KamiCuk said: int, maybe of float*100, Then implement itoa.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have added an edit to the question, maybe there is a solution considering my integer values

Comment: @JoopEggen I think your solution would be hard to implement considering the large range of values i have. Maybe it woudl work by multiplying by a large 1000. Do you have code solutiion for your comment so i can test it ?

Comment: `Do you have code solutiion for your comment` solution to? Just multiply the values by a constant power. And use `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` depending on what you need. `How do i convert the message` implement your own `itoa` or your own small `printf`.. Still, I believe, you should be able to detect why you cannot use `printf` and solve the issue. There are also open-source custom `printf` implementation, not so hard to find on github, so use them. And for `arm-none-eabi-gcc` research `--specs=nano.specs`.

Comment: It isn't clear to me how i would then attach the values of V1, V2 to the char text. I usually program in Python so I am a bit lost on the correct different steps

Comment: I was told from NXP (the manufacturer of the MCU) that: 
"Adding/removing semihosting is done via the project settings, and removing any printf calls you have in your code."